SSRS code variable reset on visibility changes
I use custom code to sum a Total of group Totals. I also call the ResetTotal function in the report header to keep the variable to increase with every call of the report.
This works as expectet, but the Totals also reset on changing the visibility of groups. So if I open a detail group the Totals are change to Zero. If I change the filter of the report the Totals are back untill i open a group and the function reset the totals to Zero.
Group Variable:
 = Code.Lookup_Sum(Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!BUTS_Name.Value, Fields!Attendee.Value, Fields!VisitsCount.Value, "Visits")))

Custom Code:
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
  If items Is Nothing Then
    Return Nothing
  End If

  Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
  Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
  suma = 0
  ct = 0
  For Each item As Object In items
    suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
    ct += 1
  Next
  If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function 

Public Shared Total_Sum As Integer = 0

Public Function Lookup_Sum(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer
  Total_Sum = Total_Sum + value
  Return Total_Sum
End Function

Public Function ResetTotal()
  Total_Sum = 0
End Function

Is there a way to distinguish in the function or in the formula of the field whether the visibility has been changed or the report has been reloaded or filtered?

Many details are missing like custom code, layout, where custom code is called etc.

The total will reset when the part of the report with the =Code.ResetTotal() is triggered. Need to look at your report view to see the tables and grouping. If the Code expression is in a group section that's repeating, then it will trigger for each group.

My report has a table in with hidden columns and rows.
I have tried the code in various places.
I had the best result when the code was in the detail row in an invisible column. Nevertheless, the totals were reset when I expanded the details and then expanded the column.

correction:
I had the best result when the code was in the detail line.
In the hidden column the reset did not work at all.
